# Basic C question on copying char arrays to char pointers

Tags: c, char

I have some doubts in basic C programming.

I have a char array and I have to copy it to a char pointer. So I did the following:

```
char a[] = {0x3f, 0x4d};
char *p = a;     
printf("a = %s\n",a);
printf("p = %s\n",p);
unsigned char str[] = {0x3b, 0x4b};
unsigned char *pstr =str;
memcpy(pstr, str, sizeof str);
printf("str = %s\n",str);
printf("pstr = %s\n",pstr);
```

My printf statements for pstr and str get appended with the data "a".
If I remove memcpy I get junk. Can some C Guru enlighten me?

Comment: You don't "copy an array to a pointer". You're obtaining a pointer to the first element of an existing array. No copying.

Comment: I don't see where anything gets "appended".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a null terminator, cause that's what you printf expects:

```
char a[] = {0x3f, 0x4d, '\0'};
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, C strings (the `%s` in `printf`) are expected to be NUL-terminated. You're missing the terminators. Try `char a[] = {0x3f, 0x4d, 0}` (same goes for `str`).

Secondly, `pstr` and `str` point to the same memory, so your `memcpy` is a no-op. This is a minor point compared to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way C strings are represented is that in memory, they are a sequence of non-zero bytes representing the characters, followed by a zero (or NULL) byte. You should declare:

```
char a[] = {0x3f, 0x4d, 0};
```

When you assign a string pointer (as in `unsigned char *pstr = str;`) both pointers point to the same memory area, and thus the same characters. There is no need to copy the characters.

When you do need to copy characters, you should be using `strlen()`, the `sizeof()` operator returns the number of bytes its argument uses in memory. `sizeof(pointer)` is the number of bytes the pointer uses, not the length of the string. You find the length of a string (i.e. the number of bytes it occupies in memory) with the `strlen()` function. Also, there are standard functions to copy C strings. You should rely on those to do the right thing:

```
strcpy(pstr, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf`'s `%s` expects a 0-terminated string, your strings aren't. The uninitialized memory following your arrays may however happen to start with a 0-byte, in which case your code will *appear* to be correct - it still isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring an array "str", then pointing to it with pstr. Note that you have no null-terminating character, so after using memcpy you copy the block to itself *with no null terminator, as a string requires*. Thus, printf can't find the end of the string and continues printing until it finds a 0 (or '\0' in character terms)

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Ok so I remove memcpy since it means nothing here as pstr points to the location. Would this mean that if I do computations on the pstr, it would still  be alright( I mean like pass this to some function to read the string stored etc) without null termination, since it was the problem with printf not finding it? I mean as long as I dont print the string,i neednt use null char at the end or??

Comment: if you don't null-terminate the string, however, how do you expect to find the end of it? in this example, sure, you know the end is 0x4d, but what if the user was inputting a string? it's good practice to nullterminate it in any case, so you really should be doing so

Comment: ok I shall certainly shall then. Thanks for all your elaborate commets.

Comment: no worries. feel free to mark the answer you believe best answers your question, that way other users can know that this question has been solved

Answer (score -1):

Agreed. You'll have to add a null byte at the end of your array of chars.

```
char a[] = {0x3f, 0x4d, '\0'};
```

The reason being is that you're creating a string without declaring where it actually ends. Your memcpy() function copies *str to *pstr and automatically adds a null byte for you, which is why it works.

Without memcpy() there the string never knows when to end, so it reaches into subsequent memory addresses and returns whatever random values are stored there. When you're creating a string out of characters, always remember to end it with a null byte.

Comment: No, this is not correct.  memcpy strictly observes the provided `n` argument:

`The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.`